# Websocket with Gui

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, websocket, pyqt5

My first class allows me to connect to the websocket, the second class allows me to try to have a graph to display the data.

On the code, I just try to display a graph while the weboscket is running using pyqtgraph but the window is completely buggy.

Thanks

```
import asyncio
import json
import websockets
from asyncqt import asyncSlot, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg

class Ws(QtCore.QObject):
    dataChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(dict)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._websocket = None

    @property
    def websocket(self):
        return self._websocket

    async def connect(self, server,):
        self._websocket = await websockets.connect(server)
        await self.on_message()

    @asyncSlot(dict)
    async def on_message(self):
        while True:
            message = await self.websocket.recv()
            message = json.loads(message)
            self.dataChanged.emit(message)


    @asyncSlot(dict)
    async def send_message(self, message):
        while self.websocket is None:
            await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
        data = json.dumps(message)
        await self.websocket.send(data)

    def run(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.create_task(self.connect(server="wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime"))
        loop.run_forever()

class TestUi(object):
    def __init__(self):

        self.plt = pg.plot()

        self.ws = Ws()
        self.ws.send_message(
            {"op": "subscribe", "args": ["instrument:XBTUSD"]})
        self.ws.dataChanged.connect(self.update_data)
        self.ws.run()

    def update_data(self, data):
        print(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    u = TestUi()
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to set the eventloop of asyncqt:

```
import asyncio
import json
import sys
import websockets


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

import pyqtgraph as pg

from asyncqt import QEventLoop, asyncSlot


class Ws(QtCore.QObject):
    dataChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(dict)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._websocket = None

    @property
    def websocket(self):
        return self._websocket

    async def connect(
        self, server,
    ):
        self._websocket = await websockets.connect(server)
        await self.on_message()

    @asyncSlot(dict)
    async def on_message(self):
        while True:
            message = await self.websocket.recv()
            message = json.loads(message)
            self.dataChanged.emit(message)

    @asyncSlot(dict)
    async def send_message(self, message):
        while self.websocket is None:
            await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
        data = json.dumps(message)
        await self.websocket.send(data)

    def run(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.create_task(self.connect(server="wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime"))
        loop.run_forever()


class TestUi(object):
    def __init__(self):

        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        loop = QEventLoop(app)
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

        self.plt = pg.plot()

        self.ws = Ws()
        self.ws.send_message({"op": "subscribe", "args": ["instrument:XBTUSD"]})
        self.ws.dataChanged.connect(self.update_data)
        self.ws.run()

    def update_data(self, data):
        print(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    u = TestUi()
```